# How to load chunk files made by Webpack during runtime?

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack

How to load chunk files which were generated by webpack 1.12.9?
Does the webpack bootstrap script automactically load chunk files during runtime?
Or.... do I have to manually import those chunk file in web page by script tag?

The situation is that I have a cordova web app which is modulized by amd (asychronous module definition).
Since there are some defects of design in it's architecture, we have to load javascript separately in our web page.
We want to load frameworks and framework initialization code inside head tag, and rest of all stuff in the end of body tag.
The structure of my page is demonstrated below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--ignored-->
        <script src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script><!-- frameworks e.g. jquery-->
        <script src="js/boot.js"></script><!-- framework initialization -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Several pages in this SPA -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script><!-- main entry point -->
        <script src="js/delivery.js"></script><!-- other modules -->
   </body>
</html>
```

But if I build my web page by webpack settings below, then my browser will try to load jquery from the root path of my site during runtime.
For example, requirejs attempts to load jquery from http://localhost:8000/browser/www/jquery instead of getting it from chunk files which has included frameworks built up this SPA.
This problem crashes my app.

```
{
    entry: {
        boot: "./src/js/boot.js",
        main: "./src/js/main.js",
        delivery: "./src/js/module/dev/delivery.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "www/js"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
        //,libraryTarget:"amd"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [
           path.resolve('./src/js')
        ],
        alias: {
            "jquery":path.join(__dirname, jquerySrcPath),
            "jquery.mobile":path.join(__dirname, jqmSrcPath),
            "jqm-and-i18next-config":path.join(__dirname, "src/js/jqm-and-    i18next-config.js"),
            "jquery.i18next":path.join(__dirname, "src/lib/jquery-i18next-plugin-for-synnex/i18next.amd.withJQuery-1.8.0.js"),
            "underscore":path.join(__dirname,    "src/lib/underscore/underscore.js"),
            "backbone":path.join(__dirname, "src/lib/backbone/backbone.js")
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("common.js")
    ]
}
```

I wonder what might be the root cause of this problem?
And .... if requirejs attempt to load jquery from an incorrect place is because that my web page did not load chunk files during runtime, then how to do it in the webpack suggested way?

Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you!